# Huffman Coding Using Character Based Formating

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple recursive function to return the coded values. The function would take the input string 001a1b01c1 and returns the tree and coded values. Letters are encoded as: a=00,b=01, c=10, d =11. I am using studio and trying to keep it in C. I am not sure if I am implementing the recursive.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct HuffmanNode {
    unsigned char value;
    struct leaf *left; 
    struct leaf *right;
};

HuffmanNode *decodeTree(unsigned char tree[], int &idx)
{
   if (tree[idx] == '1')
   {
       ++idx;
       return (HuffmanNode(tree[idx]));
   }

   else
   {
       idx++;
       HuffmanNode *left = decodeTree(tree, idx);
       idx++;
       HuffmanNode *right = decodeTree(tree, idx);
       return HuffmanNode(left, right);
   }

}

int main()
{
// huffman tree 001a1b011c
unsigned char HuffmanArray[24] = {'0','0', '1', 'a', '1', 'b', '0', '1', 
'1', 'c' };

int idx = 0;
HuffmanNode *codetree = NULL;

codetree = decodeTree(HuffmanArray, idx);
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?  You're including iostream.h.

Comment: I am writing in C. - Mark

Comment: If this is C, double-check that `#include`. This looks a lot like C++ using the `HuffmanNode(...)` constructor.

Comment: I corrected what I think is correct. I am having having a hard time trying to figure out the recursion process.